# how to have a pipe used inside input tag

Tags: angular, angular2-pipe, angular-pipe

```
<input [value]="control.value" currencyMask [id]="control.fieldId" [type]="text" (keypress)="onkeypress($event)">
```

The above field is supposed to be currency field. I am using currencyMask to format the field value as the user enters. But when the value is passed to the input from backend(to be shown as a pre-filled data), it doesnt get formatted.

So i am thinking to implement a pipe which formats the value in both cases. But i have no proper way to implement that.

I tried as:

*input **[value]="{{control.value | customPipe}}"** currencyMask [id]="control.fieldId" [type]="text" (keypress)="onkeypress($event)"*

it was throwing an error as **unexpected {{}}**

I am open to any better suggestions

Comment: You can't have a pipe on input tag, but you can call it in component and use `<pipe>.transform(<value>)`.

Comment: will that change the value of the model..i want the model to be plain number without commas and dollar

Comment: @developer033 its bnot advisable to call a pipe inside a component

Comment: @RahulSingh out of curiosity.. where did you find this? Why isn't It advisable?

Comment: @developer033 pipes are meant to transform a value in the template without modfying the exact value  of the model. if you want to acheive something like this then go for service method or any other function

Comment: @RahulSingh again.. any resource of this? Where did you find that it isn't advisable?

Comment: @developer033 no i dnt have but i have come across it some time i rememeber that , if this wasnt the case why do we have services everything can be in pipes right ?

Comment: How would a service help in this case? To format input? He wants something to format input.. people could suggestion directives, and yes, *Pipes* in component. I really don't know why you're saying that isn't advisable.